# Hibernate 5.2.5.Final createSQLQuery() method deprecated

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, hibernate

I'm using the `createSQL()` method in Hibernate to make an insert operation in my database.

What I want to do is declraing a custom SQL statement so that I can apply a `MD5()` function to a field on a table. That's why I can't just simply use the `save(Object)` method.

I got a warning from Eclipse IDE that says: 
`The method createSQLQuery(String) from the type QueryProducer is deprecated.`

Despite of this the insert operation is performing as expected.

The current version of Hibernate I'm using on my project is 5.2.5.Final.

So, the question would be: is there another way to achieve the same in this version of Hibernate in order to get rid of that annoying warning?

I also know adding `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` annotation will solve the issue, but I'm not pretty sure whether it will cause any problems in the future.

It's worth mentioning that I'm a begginer using this framework.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The javadoc of the deprecated [`QueryProducer.createSQL(String)`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/query/QueryProducer.html#createSQLQuery-java.lang.String-) describes what to use instead:

> Deprecated. (since 5.2) use `createNativeQuery(String)` instead
>   Create a `NativeQuery` instance for the given SQL query string.

Just adding `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` is usually no good idea,
because you may get problems in the future; i.e. when you move to a newer Hibernate version where the now deprecated method then will have been removed.

Comment: In 6, [`createNativeQuery(String)`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/query/QueryProducer.html#createNativeQuery(java.lang.String)) is deprecated in favor of [`createNativeQuery​(String sqlString, Class<R> resultClass)`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/query/QueryProducer.html#createNativeQuery(java.lang.String,java.lang.Class))